# Getting min,max,mean,std from array field in hive by sql

Tags: sql, hive

I have a hive table like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE spare_table(
  id int,
  value array<float>,
  value2 array<float>
)
stored as orc tblproperties ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY");
```

and data:

```
+---+----------+----------+
| id|     value|    value2|
+---+----------+----------+
|  1|[1.0, 2.0]|     [9.0]|
|  2|[1.0, 2.0]|     [9.0]|
|  3|     [9.0]|[1.0, 2.0]|
|  4|[1.0, 2.0]|[1.0, 2.0]|
+---+----------+----------+
```

I want to get **min,max,mean,std** of `value` array field in hive by sql. I expect to get the result as follows:

```
+---+----------+----------+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+
| id|     value|    value2|min|max|avg|std|min2|max2|avg2|std2|
+---+----------+----------+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+
|  1|[1.0, 2.0]|     [9.0]|1.0|2.0|1.5|0.5| 9.0| 9.0| 9.0| 0.0|
|  2|[1.0, 2.0]|     [9.0]|1.0|2.0|1.5|0.5| 9.0| 9.0| 9.0| 0.0|
|  3|     [9.0]|[1.0, 2.0]|9.0|9.0|9.0|0.0| 1.0| 2.0| 1.5| 0.5|
|  4|[1.0, 2.0]|[1.0, 2.0]|1.0|2.0|1.5|0.5| 1.0| 2.0| 1.5| 0.5|
+---+----------+----------+---+---+---+---+----+----+----+----+
```

I tried

```
select id,min(value),max(value),AVG(value),stddev(value),min(value2),max(value2),AVG(value2),stddev(value2) from feature_info
```

show error:

> FAILED: UDFArgumentTypeException Only primitive type arguments are
>   accepted but array is passed.

I don't know how to get them from array field. Can someone help me?

**Update**
I can't do `lateral views` for some reason. Is there any way to use it directly on array field?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below, it should help

```
hive> desc array_test;
OK
c1                      int
c2                      array<decimal(1,0)>
Time taken: 0.09 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
hive> select * from array_test;
OK
1       [1,2,3]
2       [2,3,4]
Time taken: 0.14 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)

hive> select c1, c22 from (select c1, c2 from array_test) a lateral view explode(a.c2) exploded as c22;
OK
1       1
1       2
1       3
2       2
2       3
2       4

hive> with res1 as (select c1, c22 from (select c1, c2 from array_test) a lateral view explode(a.c2) exploded as c22) select c1, min(c22), max(c22), avg(c22) from res1 group by c1;
OK
1       1       3       2.0000
2       2       4       3.0000
```

You can go through - https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/222388/hive-split-for-columns.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Did you have any idea to solve it without `lateral views`? I can't do it for some reason. Is there any way to use it directly on array field?

Answer (score 0):

```
select
*
,val_s[0] as v1_min
,val_s[size(val_s)-1] as v1_max
,val2_s[0] as v2_min
,val2_s[size(val2_s)-1] as v2_max
,(val_s[0] + val_s[size(val_s)-1])/2 as avg_v1
,(val2_s[0] + val2_s[size(val2_s)-1] ) /2 as avg_v2
from
(select *
        ,sort_array(value) as val_s
        ,sort_array(value2) as val2_s
        from table
) a
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my array has no fixed length, and this answer does not get `std`.